# facebook "Message Us" button not work personal account

Tags: javascript, facebook

I using the [Message US](https://whatshelp.io/widget/?utm_campaign=multy_widget&utm_medium=widget&utm_source=220.133.105.133) plugin to set facebook Messenger.

However, I found that this feature seems to be only able to set the fan page account.
Personal page is not working.I don't know it's FB only supports fan pages, or I didn't open an FB license. I sent EMAIL to developers but I didn't receive a response.
[image]

for example: the plugin code,  `facebook: "pageID"` << this `pageID` only set fans page ID or pade name,like this `https://www.facebook.com/angularjobs/` to set `angularjobs` in `facebook:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
            facebook: "pageID", // Facebook page ID
            company_logo_url: "//static.whatshelp.io/img/flag.png", // URL of company logo (png, jpg, gif)
            greeting_message: "Hello, how may we help you? Just send us a message now to get assistance.", // Text of greeting message
            call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
            position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        };
        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: The messenger platform has the purpose of connecting users with pages, not with other user profiles.

Comment: pages?Do you mean fan page?

Comment: https://keyreply.com/chat/ , the plugin can be connect personal messager, but it is to open a new page, not a small window

Comment: Yes, fan page. Anything that would connect to an actual user profile instead of a page would not be allowed to begin with.